# ajaxComplete not working on $(window)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery version 1.5.1 and this isn't working for me:

```
    $(window).ajaxComplete(function() {
        console.log('hello');
    });
```

but this is:

```
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        console.log('hello');
    });
```

Why can't I attach the event handler to `$(window)`?

***Note: this code is working with jQuery v1.3.2 but not with v1.5.1***

Comment: why do you want to attach to the window?... in the browser there is only 1 window and 1 document... thus no benefit I can see by tying to the window?

Answer (score 5):

Probably because `window` is

> 1.) Not an element
>
> 2.) Somewhat 'protected' by the browser's js engine
>
> 3.) a bad idea when looking for something to attach an AJAX event to

Why can't you use `document` or an element instead?

Comment: I was just curious, cause it worked in an earlier jQuery version but stopped after I upgraded to v1.5.1. Thank you for your reply!